# Handlebars #each for object or array

Tags: handlebars.js

I am having an issue where sometimes the object I want to iterate through is just a plain object but sometimes it's an array, for both I am using the `{{#each}}` Handlebars built-in helper.

When the object is an array, it works just fine, but when it is a plain object it is not working. How can I get around that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

when iterating over properties `{{@key}}` refers to property name, and  `{{this}}` refers to property value

more here
https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each